# Does ip command support wildcards?

Tags: linux, command-line, ip, command

I'd like to list let's say all of the following interfaces:

- `p4p1`
- `p4p2`
- `p4p3`
- `p4p4`

Instead of doing something like this:

```
for i in {1..4}; do ip a s p4p${i}; done
```

can I just do something similar to:

```
ip a s p4p*
```

and achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `ip addr help`:

```
[...]
ip addr {show|save|flush} [ dev STRING ] [ scope SCOPE-ID ]
                     [ to PREFIX ] [ FLAG-LIST ] [ label PATTERN ] [up]
[...]
```

You can use:

```
ip addr show label p4p\*
```